# azure-ad and jwt authentication with azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-api-management

I've below inbound policy block to validate `jwt` tokens while connecting to APIs hosted on azure APIM service.

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." require-scheme="Bearer">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id}}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>{{azure-managed-api}}</audience>
                <audience>{{api-audience}}</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>{{aad-issuer-url}}</issuer>
            </issuers>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud">
                    <value>{{azure-managed-api}}</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

This works fine for CLI kind of clients like curl etc., Nevertheless, I would like to make it work with browser too.

My requirement is that if someone accesses the API with browser, the API policy should check for `Bearer` token, if absent user should be redirected to Azure AD to create the token & use it to authenticate with the API.

I searched for lot of resources but couldn't find one. If you have such a snippet, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the issue at my environment by using the following policy and it redirected me to azure AD for token generation**

Before requesting, add you redirect URL in **Authentication**

[image]

[image]

**`APIM Policy`**

**Please note**, If you are using Azure AD v1 then use `resource=<scope>`  or else use `scope=<scope>` in the authorize url mentioned in the below policy. Refer this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/use-oauth2-for-authorization).

```
<policies>
<inbound>
<base  />
<choose>
<when  condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("User-Agent", "").Contains("Chrome") || context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "").StartsWith("Bearer  "))">
<!-- Token validation -->
<validate-jwt  header-name="Authorization"  failed-validation-httpcode="401"  failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."  require-scheme="Bearer">
<openid-config  url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/.well-known/openid-configuration"  />
<audiences>
<audience>{audiance}</audience>
</audiences>
<issuers>
<issuer>https://sts.windows.net/tenant_id/</issuer>
</issuers>
<required-claims>
<claim  name="aud">
<value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
</claim>
</required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
</when>
<otherwise>
<!-- Redirect to Azure AD for authentication -->
<return-response  response-variable-name="unauthorizedResponse">
<set-status  code="302"  reason="Found"  />
<set-header  name="Location"  exists-action="override">
<value>https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&amp;response_type=token&amp;redirect_uri=https://xxxxxxxxxx.azure-api.net/echo/resource?param1=sample&amp;subscription-key=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&amp;resource=<scope></value>
</set-header>
</return-response>
</otherwise>
</choose>
</inbound>
<backend>
<base  />
</backend>
<outbound>
<base  />
</outbound>
<on-error>
<base  />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

**You can get the scope from below**-

From api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, only use xxxxxxxxxxxx in `resource=<scope>`

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]

It will ask you to choose an account to login to Azure AD

[image]

Once you will provide the Admin approval, It will first amend the token in the URL and then will be redirected to that URL which you have provided in `redirect_url`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ikhtesam, Thanks for the answer. Much of this works but I do have a problem constructing redirect URL. I would like to redirect to the url visited in the first instances not to a fixed URL. For example, if I try to access `https://xxx.azure-api.net/v1/haha`, the APIM should get the token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` & simply redirect to the URL requested `https://xxx.azure-api.net/v1/haha` not `https://xxx.azure-api.net/`

Comment: Another observation is that when I pass the `Authorization` header with `curl`, it somehow still redirects which is incorrect IMO. I'm investigating on this part.

Comment: you can add your redirect URL in azure AD as shown in my answer, even I have added the primary URL which I had used in the initial call

Comment: For incorrectly redirection, you can change the AND operator to OR in the policy

Comment: hmm., my URI is dynamic ie., `https://xxx.azure-api.net/v1/haha` or `https://xxx.azure-api.net/v1/lol` or `https://xxx.azure-api.net/v1/lmao`. I can't add all the URIs in Azure AD. For testing purposes, I added a static, complete URI to azure AD & APIM, still it fails with `The page isn’t redirecting properly. An error occurred during a connection to xxxx.azure-api.net. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.` error