# API Management validate-jwt for graph.microsoft.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-management

I'm trying to do something that feels like it should 'just work' out of the box. I have users on a SharePoint site who have already authenticated via SSO and I'm kicking off a client-side call to get an access token for the graph api on their behalf. The token will be included in a call to an API Management endpoint which has a `validate-jwt` inbound policy.

All I want to do is make sure that token is present, valid, and was issued by my AAD instance. Its only purpose is to restrict callers of my endpoint to people within my org by providing evidence of having already been authenticated. I'm going to drop it when I call the back end and use the APIM managed identity to authenticate there.

I want this to be a low-friction implementation, so I haven't created a new app registration for users to authenticate with to get a token. My thought is that the Graph API token will suffice, and people will already have access to it. Here is the stripped-down version of the policy which feels like it should work.

```xml
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="403" failed-validation-error-message="Bad JWT" require-scheme="Bearer">
  <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID-HERE/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
  <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID-HERE/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
</validate-jwt>
```

I'm here posting, so obviously this isn't working. I'm getting the `JWT Validation Failed: IDX10511` error which feels misleading because it only fails when my token is for the graph.

So, for example, I can use the Azure CLI to get a token for the default resource (management.core.windows.net) like this:

```
az account get-access-token
```

That token, when included with a request in Postman, validates successfully.

If I change it to get one for the graph instead:

```
az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com/
```

Suddenly the APIM `validate-jwt` policy begins to fail, complaining as above about error `IDX10511`

This feels like a problem which is specific to a bearer token generated for the graph api. The website `jwt.io`, which does jwt validation, also complains about the token signature when targeting the graph, but not when targeting management.core.windows.net

Any guidance on why this isn't working or what I may have to do to fix it?

Comment: In my case it was working for cli clients with the configuration in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538441/azure-ad-and-jwt-authentication-with-azure-apim) question. Try adding `issuer` block.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `validate-jwt` for `graph.microsoft.com` resource based token.

**Policy I used**-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>https://graph.microsoft.com/</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/</issuer>
            </issuers>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud">
                    <value>https://graph.microsoft.com/</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

I am getting Signature validation failed error.

[image]

- I have noticed the token generated with resource `graph.microsoft.com` contains **nonce** in its header when you decode it using `jwt.io`. Because of this we are getting signature invalid error.

[image]

- But if you generate a token using scope as your app_id_uri/.default, then its header will not contain **nonce** in it.
- During my research, I came across this [Github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-405683736) which says in order to validate Graph API based token, we need special processing due to **nonce** and Graph token validation is not required.
- To add an extra level of security for the Users, MsGraph added **nonce** into the jwt header.

I would suggest you to create a scope in below to use for your application or else you can check with the product team.

[image]

**References**-

[validation - Invalid signature while validating Azure ad access token, but id token works - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317152/invalid-signature-while-validating-azure-ad-access-token-but-id-token-works).